# Help formatting table of contents, left margin numbers

Tags: table-of-contents

Hello I am trying to get rid of some of the numbers on the left side of the table of contents entries.  I am using the article class and I would like to eliminate numbers left of "sections" but not "subsections".  So, in the picture below, I would like to keep "1.1, 1.2, etc" but not "1"

[image]

This also happens in the document itself, with each new section it lists the number to the left.  I would like to clear those but still keep the subsection numbers.

I have taken a look at tocloft but I could not make sense of it.  If you could give any help, that would be great.  I am using Texstudio and here is what my doc looks like right now:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{references = {Works Cited}}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\makeindex
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Part I}
\printbibliography[title={Primary Works},category=primary]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's a minimal version of your document; the important code is between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`: basically we call `\l@section`, which is responsible for typesetting the entry in the table of contents after having neutralized `\numberline`. Then we redefine `\@seccntformat` which is responsible for printing the number next to the section titles (at all levels): since we define only `\sectionformat`, with `\section{Part I}` no number will be printed.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\let\latexl@section\l@section
\def\l@section#1#2{\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latexl@section{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\def\@seccntformat#1{\ifcsname #1format\endcsname\else\csname the#1\endcsname\quad\fi}
\def\sectionformat{}

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Part I}
\subsection{abc}
\subsection{def}
\end{document}
```

Notice that `hyperref` should be loaded *after* the modification of `\l@section` (if you want to load it, of course).

[image]

[image]

The red rectangles are due to `hyperref`.

However I find it bad style writing “Part I” and then using an arabic number for the section.

Comment: That answer only gets rid of section numbering in the table of contents. I don't think the OP wants section numbering in the body, either...

Comment: @TSB This was not specified. :)

Comment: Yes it was. "This also happens in the document itself, with each new section it lists the number to the left. *I would like to clear those* but still keep the subsection numbers."

Comment: @TSB You're right. Fixed.

Comment: Thank you, this is great!  I had no idea how to go about this :)

Comment: @egreg Also, I just have not decided what the first part will be called.  Hence, "Part I".  I will definitely keep mixing arabic and roman numerals in mind for style though.  Thanks!

Comment: @egreg Maybe you could specify that `\l@section` is for hiding numbers in the table on contents, and that `\@seccntformat` is for hiding numbers in the document ?

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron Isn't that mentioned in the answer?

Comment: @egreg Sorry, I definitely should change my glasses :)

Answer (score 4):

(Edited according to egreg's comment, except I still prefer \phantomsection before the section command itself.) This code works, but someone else could probably make a simpler version.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\phantomsection
\section*{Part I}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Part I}
\stepcounter{section}
\subsection{abc}
\subsection{def}

\phantomsection
\section*{Part II}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Part II}
\stepcounter{section}
\subsection{ghi}
\subsection{jkl}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course it would be better to define a `\Section` macro doing the work.

Comment: Definitely, yes.

Comment: Thank you, this is an interesting idea too, using the \phantomsection.  I will keep this mind for the future. Thanks!