# toc numbering help with rearranged sections and previous solution

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I recently asked for help removing the numbers to the left of the Table of Contents and section headers.  The thread with the answer to this is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62116/help-formatting-table-of-contents-left-margin-numbers):

However, I have had to rearrange my sections to match my university guidelines and now I have a problem with the subsection numbering I kept.  I was able to reset the page counter, but not the keen-eyed table of contents, which is labeling my first part's subsections as the third section (which it is now, after the acknowledgments and preface) however I would obviously like it to remain labeling these subsections in accordance with the sections as I had them before, i.e. 1.1,1.2,etc.  A picture of what I have right now is below.

[image: table of contents with wrong section numbers]

Does anyone know a way to reset the section counter for the table of contents and remedy this problem?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your updated `\l@section` macro removes the insertion of the section number in the ToC, but the associated `section` counter is still incremented with every use of `\section{...}`. Resetting this to 0 before `\section{Part I}` should resolve your problem:

```
\section{Acknoledgements}
%...
\section{Preface}
%...
\setcounter{section}{0}% Reset section counter
\section{Part I}
%...
```

Note that such sectional (and page) counter modifications usually causes problems when including [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref). However, it's not clear whether you need this or not.