# Help formatting table of contents, left margin numbers, again

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I would like to modify the answer that I got in this thread [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62116/help-formatting-table-of-contents-left-margin-numbers) such that I have the subsection numbers in the TOC but not in the text.  I do not completely understand the workings of the code I was given.

Thanks

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

**\makeatletter
\let\latexl@section\l@section
\def\l@section#1#2{\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latexl@section{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\def\@seccntformat#1{\ifcsname #1format\endcsname\else\csname the#1\endcsname\quad\fi}
\def\sectionformat{}

\makeatother**

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Part I}
\subsection{abc}
\subsection{def}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `\def\subsectionformat{}` to your example (besides removing the error-causing asterisks).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\let\latexl@section\l@section
\def\l@section#1#2{\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latexl@section{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\def\@seccntformat#1{\ifcsname #1format\endcsname\else\csname the#1\endcsname\quad\fi}
\def\sectionformat{}
\def\subsectionformat{}

\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{Part I}
\subsection{abc}
\subsection{def}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, worked great!  I think I tried to bold some of it, hence the asterisks