# Help removing subsection and subsubsection numbers from Table of Contents TOC

Tags: table-of-contents

Hello I am trying to further modify my TOC.  I got an answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62116/help-formatting-table-of-contents-left-margin-numbers) as to how I could remove the \section numbers on the left side of the TOC and now I would like to expand that.  I would like to remove the left-hand numbering for \subsection and \subsubsection as well but I do not know how.  (I also want to keep these numbers out of the document and I am using \def\sectionformat{} to do that)

Also, my TOC is slightly over one page and so I would like to adjust the spacing from 2 to 1.5,  is there any way to do this?

[image: section numbers remeoved]

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{baskervald}
    \usepackage[margin=1in,bindingoffset=15.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
    \usepackage{filecontents}
    \usepackage{microtype}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \usepackage{indentfirst}
    \usepackage{setspace}
    \usepackage{chngcntr}\counterwithin*{footnote}{section}
    \newcommand*{\textsubscript}[1]{$#1{}$}
    \DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{references = {Works Cited}}
    \DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}
    \makeindex
    \addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
    \makeatletter
    \let\latexl@section\l@section
    \def\l@section#1#2{\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latexl@section{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
    \def\@seccntformat#1{\ifcsname #1format\endcsname\else\csname the#1\endcsname\quad\fi}
    \def\sectionformat{}
    \def\subsectionformat{}
    \def\subsubsectionformat{}
    \makeatother
    \author{}
    \title{\vspace*{36 pt}\textbf{\emph{\Huge{Big Important Title}}}\vfill}
    \date{}
    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{Part I}
    Hello World
    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want *no* number starting from subsections downwards either in the document and in the TOC, the simplest way is to say

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1} % only chapter and sections will be numbered
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}    % entries down to \subsubsections in the TOC
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked great!  Do you know how to adjust the line spacing in the TOC as well?

Comment: @Wrigley242 Just say `\begingroup\onehalfspacing\tableofcontents\par\endgroup` or, better, don't use increased spacing at all (if you can).