# Unset caption preface for figure

Tags: floats, captions, naming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change caption name of figures](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17489/change-caption-name-of-figures)

I have a caption and it reads

Figure 1: etc....

I would like to replace "Figure" with "Image".  I think the answer is similar to my other question about subsection numbering [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63422/help-removing-subsection-and-subsubsection-numbers-from-table-of-contents-toc) but I am not certain.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bindingoffset=15.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
I have some text here.  Then pics.
\newpage
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75, angle=90, width=\textwidth]{hamlet.jpg}
\caption{cool picture}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75, angle=270, width=\textwidth]{kinglear.jpg}
\caption{cool picture 2}
\end{figure}
\newpage
some more text here
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `caption` package and its `name` option.

Try:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bindingoffset=15.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[figure]{name=Image}
\begin{document}
I have some text here.  Then pics.
\newpage
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75, angle=90, width=\textwidth]{hamlet.jpg}
\caption{cool picture}
\end{figure}
\newpage
\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.75, angle=270, width=\textwidth]{kinglear.jpg}
\caption{cool picture 2}
\end{figure}
\newpage
some more text here
\end{document}
```