# How to eliminate numbers on left side of LoF

Tags: table-of-contents, floats

I would like to get rid of the numbers on the left side of my LoF, like in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62116/help-formatting-table-of-contents-left-margin-numbers) example.  I tried `\def\figureformat{}` but that did not do anything.  However, my figures are really full-page pictures inserted without a figure environment.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bindingoffset=15.5mm,heightrounded]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents\listoffigures 
\newpage
\section{part 1}
I have some text here.  Then pics.
\newpage
\vbox{
\centering
\includegraphics[angle=90, scale=0.65]{hamlet4.pdf}
\captionof{figure}[Variation in \emph{Hamlet}]{cool pic}
}
\vbox{
\clearpage
\includegraphics[angle=270, scale=0.65]{kinglear4.pdf}
\captionof{figure}[Variation in \emph{King Lear}]{cool pic 2}
}
\newpage
some more text here
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're already using the `caption` package, simply add the option `listformat=empty`. (Additionally, you may want to change/remove the indentation in the LoF.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[listformat=empty]{caption}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{0em}{0em}}% Default: 1.5em/2.3em
\let\l@table\l@figure
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures 

\newpage

\section{part 1}

I have some text here. Then pics.

\newpage

\vbox{
\centering
\includegraphics[angle=90, scale=0.65]{hamlet4.pdf}
\captionof{figure}[Variation in \emph{Hamlet}]{cool pic}
}

\newpage

Some more text here.

\end{document}
```

[image]