# Remove section number from Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, numbering

How can I remove section numbers from the Table of Contents?
My document class is `article`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\begin {document}
\tableofcontents
\section{one}
test text number one
\section{two}
test text number two
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing this using [`tocloft`](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.pdf)? (Click on link for documentation) I think using that package and adding `\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}` does the trick.

Comment: It seems useful, but how can I use that in my problem?

Comment: Can you give us a minimal working example?

Comment: Yes, of course!

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62117/61789, including only the first two rows after `\makeatletter` and then put `\makeatother`

Comment: @SeyedAmirMousavian : Add `\usepackage{tocloft}` and then `\renewcommand\numberline[1]{}` ? Seems to work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily do that with the `titlesec/titlestoc` package. It has commands that allow for a different formatting of numbered and unnumbered sections (if you want to add unnumbered sections) in the table of contents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\begin {document}
\titlecontents{section}[0em]
{\vskip 0.5ex}%
{\scshape}% numbered sections formatting
{\itshape}% unnumbered sections formatting
{}%

\tableofcontents

\section{A First Section}
Test text number one. 

\section{Another Section}
Test text number two. 

\section*{An Unnumbered Section}
Test text number three. 
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{An Unnumbered Section}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Following Astrinus's advice, you can add the two lines of code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`, given in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/62117/61789), to modify the entry in the table of contents. Here is how you can do this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\makeatletter
\let\latexl@section\l@section
\def\l@section#1#2{\begingroup\let\numberline\@gobble\latexl@section{#1}{#2}\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section{One}
test text number one
\section{Two}
test text number two
\end{document}
```

Notice that you should insure a `\newpage` is there after the `\tableofcontents`

[image]

Comment: You forgot an opening curly brace, which resulted in an error when compiling. I fixed that.